# How to clone an object with internal delegates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I wrote a sequence converter for a chemical analytic instrument. I treat each row as an object and each field of that object as another object. when a row is added to the list I need to do some updates on some field objects like order numbering, so I implemented a delegate pointing on each field object within that row. The problem occurs when I try to clone a row object, the delegate still points at the original object and just updates the field members. I have tried to unregistered the listeners on the clone and register it back, but it still runs the code on the origin object. Should I unregistered all listeners and then make the clone and register it back on the origin and the clone? What Is the best way to do this?

A second question: I tried to use the Delegate.RemoveAll function but couldn't figure out what to pass. It says target and method as delegates. Is there someone who has used it?

Comment: Best idea: try to avoid delegates here.

Comment: This sounds like you need a DataTable object?

Answer (score 0):

Using delegates has made the object stateful instead of stateless. To achieve a stateless object it would need all of its properties to be self contained so that a clone operation would do just that, be a clone but not an original.

Since it is a stateful object, one would need to create a management object (or a copy constructor) which could smartly traverse the original and recreate the new object without the original's delegates but the proper *ones* of its own.